# Problems converting polygon to point

Tags: arcgis-10.0, polygon, point, arcgis-desktop, arctoolbox

I'm trying to convert polygons to points with ArcGIS 10. My polygon layer has 2 attributes that I want to give to my point layer. I'm using the *Feature to Point* function from the Arctoolbox, but it always results in certain polygons having two or more points. I tried without and with the *inside* option. Anyone have a solution?

Thanks

Comment: A layer has one attribute . may be you talk about 2 fields.

Comment: Do you have overlapping polygons? If so, you could use the selection chip to try and visualize them.

Comment: Using GeoWizards will solve your issue see http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/gw_NoRestrictions.htm Polygon To Point

Comment: I just checked the [**Feature To Point help**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003m000000) and the Polygon Input diagram there indicates that a multipart polygon (with two parts) will result in only one point while a singlepart polygon there does the same.  Have you compared the number of polygon features (rows in your attribute table) with the number of output points - they should be the same.

Comment: As PolyGeo suggested my first thought would be that you have overlapping, perhaps duplicate, polygons.  But in my experience with fairly large feature classes, e.g. 40,000+ polygons, several points may be placed by ArcGIS at an edge such that other tools (e.g. Feature to polygon using points for attributes, or Hawth's Tools count points in a polygon) will recognize two points in a polygon. It is repeatable.  You might play around with the tolerance setting or do, as I do when it happens, manually move the points.

Answer (score 4):

Give it a try in [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/). You would use Extract Node in Vector > Geometry Tools. You may want to first use Multipart to Singleparts in the same menu.