# Convert polygon to point with QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, geometry-conversion

I work with QGIS and I tried to convert polygon into point. I need points all over the perimeter of the polygon. I saw several answers like:

[Problems converting polygon to point](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58552/problems-converting-polygon-to-point)

but I didn't see an answer.

Comment: Could you please [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/130208/edit) your question and add what you tried and what error messages (if any) you received? Have you tried using the SAGA tool **Convert polygon/line vertices to points** from the _Processing Toolbox_?

Comment: You should also specify if you want a single (center) point or all corner points of the polygon.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In QGIS to convert a polygon into a point you would use the Polygon Centroids tool.

This is found under Vector>Geometry Tools>Centroids...

This will also preserve attributes and puts the point in the geometric centroid of the polygon.

Edit:

For points around the perimeter, you will want, as mentioned, Vector>Geometry Tools>Extract Nodes...
This will also preserve attributes.

A few things to note that might be useful. If you want more dense points you can use the:
Vector>Geometry Tools>Densify Geometries...

The number of vertices to add is how many nodes will be added to each segment. So a box with 4 nodes to begin with, and densified by 4 will contain 20 nodes, 4 added to each side (segment).

Also after run, each of the Extracted Nodes will be their own geometry, so running the:
Vector>Geometry Tools>Singleparts to multipart... Using some unique id in the original polygons, to create a multipart point.

Comment: i wanted points all a round the perimeter of the polygon and not in the center of it

Comment: That is answered in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58552/problems-converting-polygon-to-point

Comment: `Vector > Geometry Tools > Polygon Centroids` is now just `Vector > Geometry Tools > Centroids`

Comment: Thanks, updated the answer.